# How to conditionally use AuthenticationProvider in SpringSecurity

Tags: spring-security

We are using 2 different AuthenticationProvider in SpringSecurity to authenticate users: one is a custom AuthenticationProvider, the other one is ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider. However, we would like to configure the app so that based on the HttpServletRequest, we would allow/disallow to use the ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider. What would be a good way to implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by `based on the HttpServletRequest`? Do you want to add a special flag as query parameter or form data to the request?

Comment: I meant in the HttpServletRequest, it will contain some information about the user such as where the user is coming from (ie. ip address). So based on those info, I will decide which provider to use to authenticate.